# How to enable multithreading flag in openmpi in linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, openmpi

I tried using MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE option in openmpi. For that to work i found that i need to enable the multiple thread option in openmpi configuration. I don't know how to do that? Can someone please help me in this. Thank you in advance.I checked openmpi settings in my system. The settings for threads as follows:

```
Thread support: posix (MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: no, OPAL support: yes, OMPI progress: no, ORTE progress: yes, Event lib: yes) FT Checkpoint support: no (checkpoint thread: no)
```

How to enable MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE flag on?

Comment: You need to recompile Open MPI. Consult the output of `./configure --help` executed from the root of the Open MPI source tree.

Comment: Can you mention how to recompile the openmpi. Where do i get the configure file?@HristoIliev

Comment: Citing my previous comment: "Consult the output of `./configure --help` executed from **the root of the Open MPI source tree**." The source code of Open MPI is available on [its website](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.10/). The option that enables full threading support is `--enable-mpi-threads`.

Answer (score 4):

In openMPI 2.0.1, it is `./configure --enable-mpi-thread-multiple`. Use this to recompile openmpi, and Use `int ret = MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &prov); assert(ret == 0 && prov == MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE);` to init the MPI.

Answer (score 2):

Open MPI master branch by default is in MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, hence you wont see that option in the ./configure --help

If you wanted to configure with that try checking out to v2.x or similar and recompile with the option

- ./configure --help | grep thread ->
     --enable-mpi-thread-multiple